# Why doesn't ~ followed by :: parse

Tags: c++, c++11

During Andrei Alexandrescu's talk on error handling:

See [C++ and Beyond 2012: Andrei Alexandrescu - Systematic Error Handling in C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) (about 30 minutes in)

Andrei presents the following piece of code:

```
~Expected()
{
    using std::exception_ptr;
    if (gotHam) ham.~T();
    else spam.~exception_ptr();
}
```

This destructor is cleaning up a `union` which contains either some type `T` or a `std::exception_ptr`. The union is populated using `placement new`.

Andrei then explains that the `using std::exception_ptr;` is necessary because the following code does not parse:

```
    else spam.~std::exception_ptr();
```

This means that it is always necessary to have a using directive if you need to explicitly call the destructor of a class in a different namespace.

Why doesn't the second example parse?

Would the followng code be a valid alternative?

```
    else delete spam;
```

Does this have the same affect as explicitly calling the destructor of `std::exception_ptr`

Comment: Regarding the latter question, no. `delete` consists of calling the destructor *and* invoking `operator delete`.

Comment: I can see why it won't work with std:: but I'm surprised you need to bring it into the namespace. spam is already of type exception_ptr and you are just invoking the destructor for memory that was allocated with placement new?

spam is presumably a reference not a pointer given you use . not -> but delete &spam invalid too if placement new was used.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, thanks, this question offers some further explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783993/placement-new-and-delete

Comment: You can work it around with an aias template: `template<typename T> using alias = T;` then write `spam.~alias<std::exception_ptr>()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Andrei probably uses `using std::exception_ptr;` because his compiler is broken.

There's no need. `spam.~exception_ptr();` should compile just fine without it.

> 3.4.5/3. If the unqualified-id is ~type-name, the type-name is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression. If the type T of the object expression is of a class type C, the type-name is also looked up in the scope of class C.

It indeed compiles with gcc.

If you need to use qualified-name for some reason, `spam.std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr();` also compiles.

Comment: Ah, I had not read that clause in the standard. Andrei must have used Microsoft's compiler, which is the one I also used and behaves that way.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that `~std::exception_ptr()` is not really the name of the function you are trying to call, but just `~exception_ptr()`. And, since it belongs to a class in a different namespace, it is inaccessible (EDIT: though it should be accessible according to §3.4.5/3 in the C++11 standard, as n.m. points out in his answer, but Microsoft compiler behaves this way).

You have an alternative to bringing the class into your namespace: do an explicit call using the qualified class name:

```
else spam.std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr(); // This is legal
```

As for your second question, as R. Martinho Fernandes correctly explained in a comment, calling the `delete` operator is not equivalent to just calling the destructor: it also calls the awkwardly named function `operator delete()`.

Comment: remember that this will inhibit the virtual function call mechanism. so if `spam` would be a reference or pointer (`spam->`), this will cease to work.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `spam.~std::exception_ptr` isn't allowed because the grammar ask for an id-expression and `~std::exception_ptr` isn't one, as Gorpik pointed, you need `spam.std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()`. But I'm not understanding the reason why qualification is needed, in the clause describing the syntax, it is reminded that

> because the name of a class is inserted in its class scope (Clause 9), the name of a class is also considered a nested member of that class.

so I think that `spam.~exception_ptr()` should be valid even without a using clause.  BTW

```
namespace ns {
struct Foo {};
}

void f()
{
    ns::Foo x;
    x.~Foo();
}
```

compile cleanly with all g++ I've access to (included the very old 2.95).  That seems to confirm my opinion that if it doesn't work in the context of the updated union types of C++11, it's a bug in the implementation.

Edit, with  g++ 4.7.1, the following compiles as well with -std=c++11.

```
namespace ns {
struct Foo {};
}

struct Bar {};

union U {
    ns::Foo f;
    Bar b;
};

struct C {
    bool b;
    U u;
    ~C() {
        if (b)
            u.f.~Foo();
        else
            u.b.~Bar();
    }                
};

void f()
{
    C c;
}
```

so Andrei has be side-tracked (either by a bug in the compiler he was using or by forgetting the fact that class names are imported in the scope of a class) trying a problem which didn't need to be solved.

Comment: VS2010 (the compiler I am using) works as explained in the question. Reading §12.4/12, I understand that the explicit call must use the type name (in this case, `std::exception_ptr`), but this should also be the name of the function called, which is not true. Anyway, this is not too clear for me: I don't know who is right in this case, VS (and Alexandrescu) or GCC.

Comment: Ah, reading n.m.'s answer, I had not looked at that clause in the standard. Now I think VS is wrong.