# calloc(), malloc() vs new-ing a struct that has an unordered_map inside

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, calloc

I am creating a struct that has a field that is an unordered_map on the heap. When I use new, I can add to it with no problem. But with calloc, I get an error inserting because the bucket size is 0. It works fine after I call reserve.

So, when calloc is called on the struct, does the unordered_map constructor not run? I am confused why if it was in a struct that was new-ed, it seems to have a non-zero bucket size. And is there a better way to go about this besides calling the reserve? (I can't use delete in this case, so I need to stick with the calloc call)

Comment: Why are you forced to use calloc?

Comment: it's legacy code. I'm just adding a new field to it which happens to be an unordered map.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose that means you can't use placement new either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, `malloc()` et al don't run constructors, whereas `new` does.

You can't rely on the fact that calling `reserve()` after `calloc()` appears to fix the problem. It doesn't. The behaviour of your code is still [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and it can blow up at any moment and in any way it pleases.

One way to fix the problem is to use [placement `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783993/placement-new-and-delete) to call the `unordered_map`'s constructor.

Alternatively, you could turn the field into a pointer, `calloc()` the `struct`, and then use `new` to allocate and construct the `unordered_map`. If you do this, you'll have to manually `delete` it.

Answer (score 1):

C memory allocation functions don't usually call constructors. See [malloc vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new). The first answer sums it up quite nicely: *don't* use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Usually? They'll *never* call the constructor. (well, `char` may be the one exception)

Comment: Seeing as I cannot possibly know the behaviour of every implementation, I stuck with usually.

Answer (score 0):

`calloc` does nothing to initialize your objects qua objects. It's basically handing you a pointer to some memory filled with zeroes. So any internal fields that require initialization, like your map, don't get it. **You shouldn't be using calloc in conjunction with objects.** (Indeed, you probably shouldn't need it at all.)