# What is the difference between delete and calling destructor in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

As stated in the title, here is my code:

```
class Foo {

    public:
        Foo (int charSize) {
            str = new char[charSize];
        }
        ~Foo () {
            delete[] str;
        }
    private:
        char * str;
};
```

For this class what would be the difference between:

```
int main () {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(10);
    delete foo;
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main () {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(10);
    foo->~Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should never have a reason to call a destructor explicitly except for a few situations in which you'll know you need to.

Comment: @chris Such as working around the lack of a placement delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783993/placement-new-and-delete

Comment: @ScottJones, Exactly.

Comment: A similar situation happened to me. I had two pointers, ptr1 and ptr2, pointing to the same memory location on the heap. I used ptr1 to call destructor explicitly but then I could access to that location with ptr2. but when I used delete on ptr1, I could no longer access with ptr2 to my object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Calling a destructor releases the resources owned by the object, but it does not release the memory allocated to the object itself. The second code snippet has a memory leak.

Comment: What do you mean by "releases resources owned by the object"? Things like files, locks?

Comment: @heretoinfinity in most cases it's dynamically-allocated memory for storing things outside of the object itself, but files and locks are excellent examples, too.

Comment: I am somewhat confused and need clarity. By "second snippet" in your answer, do you mean the line with `delete foo;` or `foo->~Foo();`? Does the destructor `foo->~Foo()` not free up memory and since the destructor has the `delete` statement?

Comment: @heretoinfinity `foo->~Foo()` does not free up the dynamic memory for the object itself. It does free up the memory for `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a call to destructor is made , the allocated memory to the object is not released but the object is no longer accessible in the program.
But delete completely removes the object from memory.