# Why is my new allocated pointer automatically deleted on program exit?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

I have the following class which I save in a file in binary mode:

```
class lol
{
public:
    ~lol() {
        std::cout << "destucted" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    int age;
    std::string name;
};
```

Now in my main I have this:

```
int main()
{
    {
        lol kar;
        kar.age = 17;
        kar.name = "Blabla";

        ytxt("class").Write(std::string((char*)&kar, sizeof(kar))); //Saves the class in binary mode
    }

    lol * asd;

    {
        std::string stClass = ytxt("class").Read();//reads the file in binary
        asd = (lol*)new char[stClass.length()];//asd is now allocated with new
        memcpy_s(asd, stClass.length(), stClass.c_str(), stClass.length());//copy the content of the file into the class
    }

    std::cout << "Name: " << asd->name << std::endl;//output
    std::cout << "Age: " << asd->age << std::endl;

    asd->age = 79;
    std::cout << "Age: " << asd->age << std::endl;

    delete asd;//I cannot delete it as lol
    //delete (char*)asd;//works but lol destructor is not called
    system("pause");
}
```

The content of the `asd` pointer is being printed to the console, the pointer is deleted and the destructor is called. At the end the exception is thrown.

When I do not delete the `asd` pointer everything is working fine, but the destructor of the `asd` pointer is not called. I know that the pointer is allocated as `new char` and I have to delete it as a `new char`, but is there another way where the delete operation calls the destructor of `lol`?

Comment: What is `ytxt`. Does it serialize the string properly? Or just dumping the pointers.

Comment: Why do you create the object as `new char[stClass.length()]` and not as `new lol()`?

Comment: This is going to end up joining the cast-of-hundreds of similar questions where someone attempts to trivially blob-manage a non POD type. And the sad thing is the attempts to do so are so divergent in their wording, titles,and code samples, it is nearly impossible to trivially find one of those hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some C++ structures can be written and read as raw bytes and work in reasonable ways.  The kind that works that way is called "plain old data", or pod for short.  (In C++11 they broke it down into finer grained concepts, but that is a detail.)

A struct or class (same thing other than default public vs private) containing nothing but pod, no virtual, no destructors, no constructors, and built-in types like `int` or pointers and arrays to same is plain old data.

Reading/writing those as a stream of bits at least does something half sensible.

If it contains pointers, the address of the thing pointed to won't survive past program restart, so avoid that.

`std::string` does not qualify, and neither does anything containing it.

To save/load from a file you should look at the serialization problem.  There are many, many techniques, but none of them are free.

As easy one is to define a free `save( put_here, X const& _` function for some output archive type `put_here`.  Then create overloads for it for each type you want to support.  Do the same for `load`.  For composite types, just save/load each element.

Adding tags and the like for versioning is also useful in non-trivial code.

For sequence containers like string, you can save it as `save(here, str.size()); for (auto&&c:str)save(here, c);`

Answer (score 4):

```
ytxt("class").Write(std::string((char*)&kar, sizeof(kar)));
```

This line does save a dump of bytes. But you *cannot* load that dump of bytes and expect it to be a proper instance of your class again. That is not how binary serialization works. This only works for POD types (and probably not by that exact line either). If you want to save your data and load it later, you will need a different method.

Every other problem in your program comes down to having byte garbage where correct data should be.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you fix your destructor, this code has no chance of working: storing bytes of an object that contains pointers and then trying to restore that object into another memory is incorrect.

Your `lol` class has `std::string`, which stores a pointer to the actual bytes of the string. When you copy bytes of `kar` into a file, you store pointers from your running program, and you do not store the content of the string itself.

When you restore an instance of `lol` from a file, its pointer is pointing to a piece of memory that has been de-allocated by `kar`'s destructor. This is undefined behavior.

You need to change your approach to serializing the object. The approach that you currently have cannot be salvaged.

**Note:** Situations when you place a class into memory allocated as an array of bytes require *placement* `new` operator. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6783993/335858) for information on how to do clean-up after placement new.

Comment: Basically I need to replace the `std::string` with a static `char` array and replace the destructor with a function I need to call before deleting the pointer (if I want a destructor). Is that right?

Comment: @terrakuh If you have flexibility to make this change, it's going to work without a constructor/destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Since your lol class contains a std::string, which is a complex object and has its internal memory management, trying to delete it when it in fact is not a real object but some random bytes from a file, will result in memory corruption/crash.