# Do I need to destroy each instance of new class?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, destructor

Essentially, if I create multiple instances of a new class, do I need to call the destructor for each instance, or will invoking it once destroy each instance(I apologize if I'm using vague/wrong terms, constructors/destructors are concepts I don't fully grasp yet).

To be more specific, this is some code I'm working with(I'll have to apologize again if the style is bad, I had an idea for a school problem and wanted to get the code down quickly).

```
while(read >> f >> l >> t >> s >> sta >> acct >> bal)
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    ptr[i] = new account(f,l,t,s,sta,acct,bal);
    ptr[i]->printcontents();
    cout << "test" << endl;
    i++;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

So for the sake of the question, assume this'll loop three times. Will I only have to invoke the destructor of "account" once to destroy all three instances of new account, or will one call leave the other two? Is this even a good practice?

Edit: I noticed some of my post got cut off, so I added the last few lines, but people have already addressed that issue. The reason I'm user pointers is purely because the assignment dictates I do so; quite frankly I don't see the point in using them at this moment, but I assume somewhere down the line they become useful. I should also add that dynamic memory allocation is also supposed to be used in the assignment.

Comment: Use smart pointers (i.e. `shared_ptr`/`make_shared` or `unique_ptr`/`make_unique`) and don't bother about deleting your `new`ed instances.

Comment: As always: Every `new` needs exactly one `delete` and every `new[]` exactly one `delete[]`. However, you basically never need `new` and `new[]` even less often to begin with.

Comment: The real question is why you are using pointers to begin with. Did you come from Java, where all objects are created with `new`? Your array of `account` objects could just store *actual `account` objects*.

Comment: You don't *call* the destructor in C++ (except in rare circumstances, which you will not encounter for a long time, if ever). `delete` and `delete[]` do that as part of their operations, as does the destruction of automatic objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destructors are called automatically and you usually don't have to worry about it **unless** you're allocating memory dynamically with `new`.

In that case, you will have to call `delete` for each allocated memory once you don't need it any more.

Note that if you're allocating an array with `new []`, you will have to use `delete[]` for desallocation:

```
int *a = new int[10]; // allocating an array of 10 integers

//...

delete[] a; // release memory
```

In modern C++, you should consider managed pointers which will do the job for you. Something like:

```
while(read >> f >> l >> t >> s >> sta >> acct >> bal)
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    ptr[i] = std::make_unique<account>(f,l,t,s,sta,acct,bal);
    ptr[i]->printcontents();
    cout << "test" << endl;
    i++;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Here, `std::make_unique` will return a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) which will call delete on the associated memory when destroyed.

---

Last point : are you sure you really need pointers? Hard to say from your example, but depending on your usage you may as well create statically allocated objects:

```
while(read >> f >> l >> t >> s >> sta >> acct >> bal)
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    ptr[i] = account(f,l,t,s,sta,acct,bal);
    ptr[i].printcontents();
    cout << "test" << endl;
    i++;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: To give a little more context, this is supposed to be part of a bank program, wherein I use an array of pointers to account objects that store account information(name, account number etc.). Initially, I declared

account *ptr[10]

and tried to access member function of class account(account.h is included), like this

ptr[i]->setacctnum(acct);

but that caused the program to crash. I don't see why this didn't work, but that's where I'm at now.

Comment: Declaring `account *ptr[10]` creates an array of **uninitialized** pointers to account objects. That's why your program crashed: you tried to call methods on dangling pointers. You should consider avoiding pointers and declare `account ptr[10]`: you will be able to access member functions with calls like `ptr[i].setacctnum(acct);` (notice the `.` instead of `->` since `ptr[i]` is now an object instead of a pointer). If you really need pointers, consider `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 3):

Every `new` should be balanaced with a `delete`

If you have an array of pointers, and `new` each pointer, you'd need to `delete` each instance.

If, on the otherhand you `new` an array of objects, you can then `delete []` the whole array.

As a side point, for your code instead of using the `ptr` (which you haven't told us the details of, consider just using a `std::vector<account>` and using `push_back` then it will automatically size as required, instead of `ptr[i] =  new...`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have to delete each instance you create.  Exactly how you do that depends a bit... but the simple rule of thumb:

For each use of `new` there must be a use of `delete`.

For each use of `new[]` there must be a use of `delete[]`.

If you get the instance from an auto declaration, you don't have to do anything because it will be destroyed with its stack frame; but if you created it, you destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, *if* you use `new`, *then* you'll need `delete`.  However, your real trouble is conceptual.  You ask a good question to which `new` and `delete` are peripheral.

The normal use of destructors, more than 99.5 percent of the time, is to let the compiler invoke them automatically.  (The 0.5 percent exception is abstruse.  We don't need to worry about that right now.)

Consider this code fragment:

```
  int n = 5;
  {
    int m = 2;
    ++m;
    n *= m;
    // The variable m is automatically destructed here.
  }
  // Here, n == 15.
```

See how that works?  The destructor of `m` is automatically called when `m` reaches the end of its life, which (because `m` was not made with `new`) happens at the end of the block in which `m` is instantiated.

Of course, `m` is an `int`, so its destructor doesn't do anything (or, if you prefer, `m` has no destructor).  Other types you yourself define, like your type `account`, can have destructors.  The destructor is *automatically* called against a single object at the moment that that single object, an instance of `account`, reaches the end of its life.

**NEW AND DELETE**

So, what does this have to do with `new` and `delete`?

In my code fragment, I did not use `new`.  Therefore, the lifetime of my object was controlled by the enclosing braces.

In your code fragment, you did use `new`.  Therefore, the lifetime of your object is controlled by your use of `delete`.

Of course, you forgot to use `delete`, so that is why your object was never destructed (except maybe when your whole program exits).

Others have noted that modern C++ provides improved alternatives to `new` which you should use in most cases.  You can read their answers for those.  However, mechanically, it is still very helpful to understand what plain `new` does, and how `delete` pairs with it.

**MANUAL INVOCATION OF THE DESTRUCTOR**

You almost certainly need not worry about this, because the cases in which a destructor is manually invoked are rare and advanced.  Basically, if you are managing yourself the memory in which an object is stored (which you almost never do, but there are rare exceptions), then the compiler can't tell when to destruct, so you must tell it when.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784035/1275653) for a typically esoteric example.

Answer (score 0):

Only pointers need call the destructor to delete them or close the program