# Exception in destructor of dynamic object

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, language-lawyer, dynamic-allocation

I came across this fringe question that I would normally dismiss with "[don't do that](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/exceptions.html#fqa-17.3)", but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer in the standard and would appreciate if someone could point out the reasoning:

Suppose a I have a class that throws an exception in the destructor:

```
struct Foo { ~Foo() { throw std::runtime_error("Catch this!"); } };
```

What happens to the dynamically allocated memory if I delete a dynamically allocated instance of this class?

```
auto p = new Foo;

try { delete p; }
catch (std::exception const &) { }
```

Is the deallocation function called or not? And why? Could I make this code correct by adding `operator delete(p);` into the `catch` block?

I ran a small test with GCC which seems to *not* deallocate the memory automatically. (Contrast this with exceptions in the *constructor*, in which case the deallocation function is guaranteed to be called (if it exists).)

Comment: No, you cannot make it correct by adding `operator delete(p)`, unless you used `operator new()` and placement new to construct the object, and then you'd need to call the destructor explicitly also.  In general, you need to keep pointers to raw allocated buffers and pointers to objects separate.  (For arrays, they may not even have the same address.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Can you back this up somehow? I just noticed that adding `operator delete(p)` does seem to make my program valgrind-clean, but is that actually UB? Isn't a `new` expression guaranteed to call `operator new`?

Comment: The Standard says "The address of the created object will not necessarily be the same as that of the block if the object is an array."  Moreover, the rules concerning calling a deallocation function require you to have gotten the pointer from the matching allocation function.

Comment: [Don't do that](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/exceptions.html#fqa-17.3)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, I know that arrays are problematic. But I thought for non-array objects there was no room for any misbehaviour...

Comment: @Kerrek: It probably works on most compilers.  But I consider it bending the rules.  Of course, [some of the rules may need to be fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4418220/103167).

Comment: For one thing, it can be pretty difficult to invoke the correct deallocation function in any sort of portable generic way.

Comment: @ChrisW: The question already said that.  It's still interesting to find out what the rules are when you go against all sane advice.

Comment: I filed a [bug report for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55635).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, the placement-array-new is definitely broken to the point of being unusable. I think someone on the DR mailing list said that there simply hasn't been anyone to write this up as a paper that's needed for a proper DR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Standard says (5.3.5p7):

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value, the *delete-expression* will call a deallocation function. Otherwise, it is unspecified whether the deallocation function will be called. [ Note: The deallocation function is called regardless of whether the destructor for the object or some element of the array throws an exception.  — end note ]

The note answers your question.

Comment: It does! Thanks :-) Wait, then there might be a bug in GCC?!

Comment: @Kerrek: Sounds like a crisis of biblical proportions!