# Visual C++ heap corruption error using delete [] and new (placement) operators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

Code snippet:

```
#include <new>
char buffer[512];

int main()
{
   double *pd;
   pd = new (buffer) double[5];
   delete [] pd;
   return 0;
}
```

This only hangs when using the placement new form of the new operator.

I'm using the following tools and options:

```
> cl -EHsc foobar.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
```

Comment: Sort of a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418220/legality-of-using-operator-delete-on-a-pointer-obtained-from-placement-new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate that memory, so you should not try to free it (with `delete []`).

In general, you would run the destructors:

```
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    T* p = pd + i;
    p->~T();
}
```

But for `double` that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd = new (buffer) double[5];
```

What you are doing there is reusing the memory that `buffer` occupied to create an array of double. So now you are deleting a memory that you didn't not allocate with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. The program didn't allocate the memory with `operator new` or `operator new[]`, so shouldn't delete it.