# Alternative for delete this when using placement new

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, this, delete-operator

I read [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) that

> As long as you’re careful, it’s okay (not evil) for an object to
>   commit suicide (delete this).
>
> Here’s how I define “careful”:
>
> You must be absolutely 100% positively sure that this object was allocated
>   via new (not by new[], nor by placement new, nor a local object on the
>   stack, nor a namespace-scope / global, nor a member of another object;
>   but by plain ordinary new).

If I use placement new, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you use placement new, you can't call `delete this` . As a matter of fact, reasons for calling `delete this`, although exist, are rare. Are you sure you have one? Aren't we seeing an XY problem?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @SergeyA: Reference required.  I believe there's actually a standard defect in this area, because the current wording appear to allow it.  "the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object".  Placement new does create an object, although it doesn't allocate.  See related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4418220/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt, wow! Good catch. Placement new is indeed a new expression, so literally reading the standard allows it. Looks like a defect to me, we all know what's gonna happen in real life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placement new is used to separate memory allocation and object lifetime, so you would usually call the destructor explicitly:

```
myobj->~myclass();
```

and free the memory later, or continue to use the memory for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Placement new means the object is not allocated on the heap, but memory for its storage is provided by the user. Delete in this case would try to deallocate a non-heap block, which is usually fatal...

There's nothing to delete, so you have to do an explicit destructor call:

```
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass() { std::cout << "Constuctor\n"; }
    ~SomeClass() { std::cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};

std::aligned_storage<sizeof(SomeClass), alignof(SomeClass)>::type storage;
new(&storage) SomeClass();
reinterpret_cast< SomeClass* >(&storage) -> ~SomeClass();
```

Having a `this` pointer only is not enough to do proper destruction in a general case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrival of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` it has become un-necessary (and undesirable) to write objects that manage their own lifetimes.

Good c++ form requires that one object has one responsibility. Your object's responsibility is the work it performs. The responsibility of a smart pointer is to manage its lifetime.

There is one remaining scenario where you would need to `delete this` - when writing an object for an old API that demands intrusive reference counting.